# Interpretation of the output from qqPlot (using car library)

Tags: r, linear-regression, normal

Basically, I have created a linear model and am testing to verify the normality of my errors. As a result, I have used the qqPlot function from the car library and have gotten the graph that can be seen below as my output.

Additionally 4 numbers were outputed (222, 160, 78, 113). My first question is, are these numbers meant to be outliers that are not consistent with the error terms being normally distributed? Secondly, what are the dashed lines that can be seen on the graph? Is this some sort of a limit where its acceptable for the error terms to be found that allow us to not question the error terms and treat them as normally distributed?

[image: 1]